# How to remove the featured image from a wordpress post without single.php

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image

How do I remove the featured image from a post (image posted on the post) without removing it from the home page of the site?

Note: I have an image site with quotations and
this is highly problematic because it discourages the post and still repeats the same message in the image twice on the page.

After querying answers to similar problem, which said that the single.php of the site should be found and remove some lines, I open a new problem:

the Neutro wordpress theme I use does not have single.php.

Any tips?

Exemple (my home page)[LINK](https://sentimentodigital.com/)

page with post and featured image [exemple](https://sentimentodigital.com/mensagens-lindas/sonhe/)

Comment: Take a look at WP template hierarchy https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png and find the file used to display your single post. After that find code like : the_post_thumbnail() and remove it :))

Answer (score 0):

Edit your themes style.css and add the following to it

```
.singular-post .entry-header figure{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work, I believe the code is described here in "featured-slider.php "

Comment: try .single-content .entry-header figure{} for your theme

Comment: @PeterCruise: Try now. Your site doens't use .single for some reason. Code updated.